How to match the coordinates of 2 shapefiles in R
I have 2 shapefiles, one of them has the coordinates of administrative units as a multipolygon, and the other has the coordinates of various sections of a border wall as a multilinestring. I am trying to match the sections of the border wall to their respective administrative units in R.
I started by importing the shapefiles:
rm(list = ls())

# Load necessary packages
install.packages("sf")
install.packages("dplyr")
library(sf)
library(dplyr)
install.packages("readstata13")
library(readstata13)
library(haven)
library(foreign)

setwd("C:/Desktop/Wall")

latlong_data14 <- st_read("Barrier_Sept_2014.shp")

setwd("C:/Desktop/Admin")

admin <- st_read("geo1_ps1997_2017.shp")

latlong_data14 looks something like this:



Shape_Leng
geometry




1900.11
MULTILINESTRING(74850...)


2109.13
MULTILINESTRING(69375...)



and admin looks like:



ADMIN_NAME
geometry




Unit A
MULTIPOLYGON(36.587...)


Unit B
MULTIPOLYGON(37.095...)



I would like to append a column to latlong_data14 with the administrative unit name, but I'm not sure how to do this. Note: it's possible that some observations span multiple administrative units, but I'm not sure. In that case, is it possible for each observation to break down how much of the shape length belongs to each administrative unit?

I think you'll first want to find all.equal(sf::st_crs(latlong_data14), sf::st_crs(admin)), TRUE prior to conducting other spatial relational tests. Likely also to adopt naming convention of lonlat, not latlon as your tools (sf, terra) expect them in lon lat order (say in a coordinate matrix).

Here is a repex that returns a linestring sf with the length of each feature per admin area. It uses the lwgeom package to split the 'barrier' linestrings. The NAME column from admin is used to define the barrier/admin relationship. Change this to match an equivalent column in your actual admin data e.g. the ADMIN_NAME column in your example data.
Also, you'll need to add or use an existing unique ID value for your barrier linestrings so you can tell which result corresponds to your original barrier features. For instance, if you look at the results below, both barrier lines intersect with Orange County. I used dplyr::mutate(ID = 1:n()) for this purpose. If you already have unique values, replace references to ID in the select() and summarise() functions with your unique value column name. Depending on the geometry column name in your data, you may also need to change st_union(x).
For the sake of simiplicity, this example uses data with a CRS of WGS84/EPSG:4326. As @Chris noted, your data do not have the same CRS. You will need to st_transform() your data so their CRS match. For maximum accuracy, you will need to ensure the CRS that you assign to your data is one that preserves distance relative to your area of interest.
Load required packages and generate example data
library(sf)
library(dplyr)
library(lwgeom)
options(scipen = 999) # For display of numeric values

# Example admin sf
admin <- st_read(system.file("shape/nc.shp", package = "sf")) %>%
  st_transform(4326)

# Example linestring sf with two barrier features
barrier <- data.frame(ID = 1:9,
                      lon = seq(-84, -76, 1),
                      lat  = rep(c(35, 35.5, 36), 3)) %>%
  st_as_sf(coords = c("lon", "lat"), crs = 4326)

sf_point <- barrier[6,]

barrier <- do.call(c, st_geometry(barrier)) %>%
  st_cast("MULTILINESTRING") %>%
  st_sfc() %>%
  st_as_sf(crs = 4326) %>%
  st_split(., sf_point) %>%
  st_collection_extract(., "LINESTRING") %>%
  mutate(ID = 1:n()) # Unique linestring ID

Generate new sf with separate barrier features with length (m) per admin feature
sf_split <- st_split(barrier, admin) %>%
  st_collection_extract(., "LINESTRING") %>%
  st_intersection(., st_difference(admin)) %>%
  select(NAME, ID) %>%
  summarise(geometry = st_union(x), .by = c(NAME, ID)) %>%
  mutate(length_m = as.numeric(st_length(.)))

# although coordinates are longitude/latitude, st_difference assumes that they are
# planar
# Warning message:
#   attribute variables are assumed to be spatially constant throughout all geometries 

sf_split
# Simple feature collection with 38 features and 3 fields
# Geometry type: GEOMETRY
# Dimension:     XY
# Bounding box:  xmin: -84 ymin: 35 xmax: -76.08275 ymax: 36
# Geodetic CRS:  WGS 84
# First 10 features:
#          NAME ID                       geometry   length_m
# 1       Avery  2 LINESTRING (-82.04743 35.97... 12317.9283
# 2    Alamance  2 LINESTRING (-79.32532 35.83...  7935.0805
# 3      Orange  1 LINESTRING (-79 36, -78.993...   895.3726
# 4      Orange  2 LINESTRING (-79.25038 35.87... 26494.0097
# 5      Durham  1 LINESTRING (-78.99374 35.99... 19071.8721
# 6    Mitchell  2 LINESTRING (-82.15366 35.92... 11239.0198
# 7      Yancey  2 LINESTRING (-82.37048 35.81... 22956.4565
# 8        Wake  1 LINESTRING (-78.86044 35.86... 37272.1897
# 9       Burke  2 LINESTRING (-81.92366 35.92... 52605.5579
# 10 Washington  1 LINESTRING (-76.59509 35.70... 20519.5451

